# Cesium.js How to get each tiles' level?

Tags: cesiumjs

I am trying to get each tiles' rectangle and level in current view, and use these information to do some ajax request.

Now I have already got all rectangles through:

```
var tileRecangles = [];
var tilesToRender = viewer.scene.globe._surface.tileProvider._tilesToRenderByTextureCount;
    if (Cesium.defined(tilesToRender)) {
        for (var j = 0, len = tilesToRender.length; j < len; j++) {
            var quadTrees = tilesToRender[j];
            if (Cesium.defined(quadTrees)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < quadTrees.length; i++) {
                    tileRecangles.push(quadTrees[i].rectangle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The question is how to get the level for each tiles?
[The value in red circles of this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaLSS.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just `quadTrees[i].level` in the same place where you have `quadTrees[i].rectangle`.

Comment: Yes, I just figure that out. Thank you